# LESS resusable nested classes

Tags: css, nested, less

Lets say that I have the following:

```
.class-1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  p{
   color: red;
  }
}
```

And I want to define in LESS a class-2 that has the same styling with the p element in the class-1. Is there any way to do so other than writing the code?

Answer (score 1):

if I understand you correctly, you want to style your `p` if it's the child of `class-1` *or* `class-2`. but `class-1` and `class-2` should have different styling.

I'd recommend writing it out twice or a different approach, but you can use **mixins** if you don't want to write it out twice.

**LESS**

```
.p() {
  color:red;
}

.class-1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  p{
   .p;
  }
}
.class-2{
  p{
    .p;
  }
}
```

**CSS output**

```
.class-1 {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.class-1 p {
  color: red;
}
.class-2 p {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.class-1, .class-2 { 
    font-weight: bold; 
    p{ 
        color: red; 
    } 
}
```